# Discrete Mathematics Proof Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

Prove or disprove that there are infinitely many $x, y, z \in \mathbb N$ such that $$\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{y^2} = \frac{1}{z^2}$$

Currently, I tried to substitute $x, y,$ and $z$ with $2n$ and $n$ and nothing seems to work.

Comment: After your edit, the problem became a completely different one.... Also, with the new edit, what is $n$?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that I put $x^n, y^n, z^n$ on the denominators. Sorry about that, its really suppose to be $x^2, y^2, z^2$.

Comment: But then what is $n$? You have $n \geq 3$ but nothing else...

Comment: I'm really sorry, I was not paying attention when I posted this question up. I removed $n \geq$. I got it mixed up with another question.

Comment: It should be all fixed now, again I apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

We begin by noting $$\frac{1}{15^2}+\frac{1}{20^2}=\frac{1}{12^2}.$$  Multiplying both sides of this equation by $\frac{1}{k^2}$ for $k \geq 1$ gives infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how you found those ratios. But that helped me alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Multiply your equation by $x^ny^nz^n$.

**The new problem** Multiplying by $x^2y^2z^2$ the new equation is

$$y^2z^2+x^2z^2=x^2y^2$$

From here it is easy to deduce that $x|yz $.

Let $yz=kx$. then the equation becomes

$$k^2+y^2=z^2 \,.$$

and $k|yz$.

If you find a solution to this equation, then you set $x= \frac{yz}{k}$.

This is easy to solve: If

$$k_0^2+y_0^2=z_0^2$$
is any solution to the pytagorean equation, then

$$(k_0^2)^2+(k_0y_0)^2=(k_0z_0)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering context, $x$, $y$ and $z$ could possibly have the same value infinite times.
That is, let $x = y = z = n$ belonging to the set of natural numbers, 
then $1/n^2 + 1/n^2 = 1/n^2$.
L.H.S. = R.H.S. for all $n$.
Hence there are infinite values for $x$, $y$, and $z$, considering $x = y = z = n$ for all $n$ belonging to the set of natural numbers.

Comment: But the equation $\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}$ is never true, except in the trivial case $n=0$. So this does not answer the question, it seems to me.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro How is it true for $n=0$?

Comment: Try $n=1$: then you are saying that $1/1^2 + 1/1^2 = 1/1^2$. In other words, $2=1$. In fact, for any $n\neq 0$ you can multiply both sides by $n^2$ and the result is $1+1=1$.

Comment: @user103816: Of course you are right: the formula is never true.